# IdentityServer - Handling expired tokens

Tags: oauth, identityserver3

A quick overview of the problem.

I have a client application that will use IDS to authorise access to a google service on behalf of the end user.

However, the client application isn't, itself responsible for talking to google. There is a Server app that does some magic with the user's data on his behalf.

Now, if I understand things correctly, the server app will use the Access Token supplied by the client app to talk to google. What happens when that access token expires? As I understand it the client application is expected to use the refresh token to as for a new access token.

Is there an issue with the *server* using this refresh token to update the access token? What flow am I supposed to use to make this magic happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server using a refresh token to get a new access token is a valid use case.

If you're working with OAuth you can use the Client Credentials or Resource Owner flows to use refresh tokens, otherwise for OpenID Connect you'll need to use Authorization Code or Hybrid.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood that. Are you saying that I can use the Resource Owner flow with a Refresh Token supplied by the Client application to request a new Access Token on the server? Can you point me to an example of how that is done please?

Comment: What technologies are you using? Are you after an implementation example or an example HTTP request?

Comment: MVC Example using IdentityModel library: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MvcCodeFlowClientManual/Controllers/AppController.cs